# NSJSONSerialization and Unicode, won't play nicely together

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, unicode

I'm in the making of an app that talks to a nodejs-server using sockets and JSON, and since iOS 5 has it's own NSJSONSerialization I thought that's may be the road to follow. Before, I used the lightweight yail library.

Anyway, after the migration to NSJSONSerialization I started to encounter problem with the encoding, before the change, the character `Ö` would send nicely to the server and back, still being `Ö`, but now, NSJSONSerialization leaves `Ö` still in unicode char i.e. `\U00f6`.

Reading the documentation says that JSON objects is converted to UTF8 by default. And when I convert the response from the server to a simple NSString, the `Ö` shows up just as expected, but it's still in JSON of course.

Please help me with your thoughts and so, should I return to yail or use the built-in NSJSONSerialization?

Thank you,
Simon

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you've determined that `NSJSONSerialization` still leaves `\U00f6` in the resulting strings?  In my testing, it decodes properly to `ö`.  Are you sure you're not confusing the default `-description` representation of the resulting `NSDictionary`/`NSArray` with it not actually decoding the result?

Comment: what do you mean? doing a simple `NSLog(@"%@", [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&err]);` outputs dictionary with a string with decoded unicode, i.e. `\U00f6`.

Comment: It's possible that the way NSLog is choosing to represent the character is with the escaped code rather than the actual character for sake of keeping the log clean.

Are you piping the data object directly from a networking library to NSJSONSerialization? Can you post some sample code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSLog calls description on its arguments, which happen to print the Unicode code instead of the character itself. Try for example:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"ö" forKey:@"hello"]);
```

And you will see that it prints

```
{
    hello = "\U00f6";
}
```

So, chances are, that your JSON decoding has been done fine.

Answer (score 0):

JSONSerialization can only be used with certain types:  NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull only by default... if you need to use other objects in your JSON, I recommend using https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit