# How can I get the Swift/Xcode console to show Chinese characters instead of unicode?

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift

I am using this code:

```
import SwiftHTTP    
var request = HTTPTask()
var params = ["text": "这是中文测试"]
request.requestSerializer.headers["X-Mashape-Key"] = "jhzbBPIPLImsh26lfMU4Inpx7kUPp1lzNbijsncZYowlZdAfAD"
request.responseSerializer = JSONResponseSerializer()
request.POST("https://textanalysis.p.mashape.com/segmenter", parameters: params, success: {(response: HTTPResponse) in if let json: AnyObject = response.responseObject { println("\(json)") } },failure: {(error: NSError, response: HTTPResponse?) in println("\(error)") })
```

The Xcode console shows this as a response:

```
{
    result = "\U8fd9 \U662f \U4e2d\U6587 \U6d4b\U8bd5";
}
```

Is it possible to get the console to show the following?:

```
{
  result = "这 是 中文 分词 测试"
}
```

If so, what do I need to do to make it happen?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect there is a bug in SwiftHTTP or perhaps something on your server. `println()` has perfectly good support for Chinese characters. I think your string doesn't contain any Chinese characters, rather it contains `"\U8fd9"` as the actual string. For example, try `println(params)` — that works perfectly.

Comment: Is there a way to convert \U8fd9 to 这 in swift?

Comment: Yes there is, I'm pretty sure it has already been answered elsewhere. However the best thing is just to avoid making the string `\U8fd9` in the first place. Find out what's doing that and stop it from doing it, that's definitely a bug.

Comment: What terms should I search for to find the answer?

Comment: You need to find out how to convert the unicode point 0x8fd9 (that's 36825 in decimal) to a string.

Comment: I supect that it's `NSDictionary`'s `description` method that does this funny escaping thing "helpfully". What happens if you print `json["result"]` instead?

Comment: Printing json["result"] produces an error that says "expected ',' separator". Printing json[result] errors as "Use of unresolved identifier 'result'.

Comment: Also, if I remove this: request.responseSerializer = JSONResponseSerializer()  then the console prints this: <7b0a2020 22726573 756c7422 3a20225c 75386664 39205c75 36363266 205c7534 6532645c 75363538 37205c75 36643462 5c753862 6435220a 7d>

Comment: Also, if I say ``````var split = request.POST("https://textanalysis.p.mashape.com/segmenter", parameters: params, success: {(response: HTTPResponse) in if let json: AnyObject = response.responseObject { println("\(json)") } },failure: {(error: NSError, response: HTTPResponse?) in println("\(error)") })`````` then I get a yellow triangle that says ```Variable split inferred to have type '()' which may be unexpected``` What is type ()?

Comment: The `description` methods of most iOS objects will not print extended Unicode characters.  And even if you bypass `description`, I'm not sure that the console will print them.

Comment: So are you saying that I should put them in to the view and see if that displays properly?

Comment: let word = "\u{8fd9} \u{662f} \u{4e2d}\u{6587} \u{6d4b}\u{8bd5}", this will print the Chinese words.

Comment: So maybe my question should be: how do I convert this object to a string?

Comment: The object you have is an NSDictionary containing one entry whose key is "result" and whose value is an NSString.  You know how to access an NSDictionary, right??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

```
println(json)
```

use

```
println((json as NSDictionary)["result"]!)
```

This will print the correct Chinese result.

Reason: the first print will call the debug description for NSDictionary which escapes not only Chinese chars.

Answer (score 2):

Your function actually prints the response object, or more accurately a description thereof. The response object is a dictionary and the unicode characters are encoded with \Uxxxx in their descriptions.

See question: [NSJSONSerialization and Unicode, won't play nicely together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143026/nsjsonserialization-and-unicode-wont-play-nicely-together)

To access the result string, you could do the following:

```
if let json: AnyObject = response.responseObject {
    println("\(json)")   // your initial println statement
    if let jsond = json as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
        if let result = jsond["result"] as? String {
            println("result = \(result)")
        }
    }
}
```

The second println statement will print the actual string and this code actually yields:

```
{
    result = "\U8fd9 \U662f \U4e2d\U6587 \U6d4b\U8bd5";
}
result = 这 是 中文 测试
```