# how to print Chinese not unicode when print NSDictionary in swift

Tags: ios, swift

when I print a NSDictionary containing Chinese, the Xcode console print unicode, how to convert the unicode to Chinese?

Comment: get idea from this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26963029/how-can-i-get-the-swift-xcode-console-to-show-chinese-characters-instead-of-unic

Comment: the solution in that link is using "println" instead of "print", but "println" has been depredicated in swift3 @MRizwan33

Answer (score 2):

try this solution

```
extension Dictionary {

    var json: String {
        let errorJson = "JSON Format error "
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self, options: .prettyPrinted)
            return String(bytes: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? errorJson
        } catch {
            return errorJson
        }
    }


}
```

using code

```
let dictionary = ["name":"ahmad","age":"22","gender":"male"]

print(dictionary.json)
```

result on log :

```
{
"name":"ahmad",
"age":"22",
"gender":"male"
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. This can print Chinese, but I think it is not a perfect solution.

Comment: Yes, it prints Chinese characters, check this output https://ibb.co/bJ3Oin